# Troubleshooting ValueError: No subgraph in the model with PyCoral

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu, pycoral

I've been working on a project using the PyCoral library to run inference on an **Edge TPU**. However, I've encountered a persistent issue where the **make_interpreter** function from the **pycoral.utils.edgetpu module throws a ValueError: No subgraph in the model.**

Here's a brief overview of my setup and what I've tried so far:

I'm on another **Asus Tinker Edge T** board after a year and trying to replicate the same project using the same model I have trained before.

I'm using a tensorflow>tensorflow-lite>edge converted .tflite model that was previously working.

The error occurs when calling **interpreter.allocate_tensors()** in my Python script.

I've confirmed that the model is compiled for the Edge TPU using the Edge TPU Compiler version **16.0.384591198**.

I've attempted to install different versions of the pycoral library, but it seems only version 0.2.0 on **PyPI** and 2.0.0 is available througout using (**pip3 install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral**).

I've also checked system-wide installations and ensured that pycoral is installed in my Python environment.
**The model and related code have not changed**, so it seems to be an issue with the environment or library versions.

The unfortunate part is that the card is **toasted** and there is no way for me to check the environment that it works well with.

Here's the relevant part of the code that's causing the error:

```
[python]
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter

interpreter = make_interpreter('model_edgetpu.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

I've considered the possibility that the TensorFlow version might be causing compatibility issues and in need of building from scratch, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause.

I've also thought about recompiling the model with the latest version of the Edge TPU Compiler, but I only have the final .tflite file.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has faced a similar issue or could provide insights into what might be going wrong. Any suggestions on how to resolve this error or further steps I could take to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!